Mobile scrolling behavior on React portalled hover-menu scrolls faster than the same swipe made directly on our editor
We have an editor inside of a webview and a portalled menu that hovers over it. When a user makes a touchstart event on the menu and then swipes up/down, the page scrolls at something like 200% or 300% the speed that it does when the user makes the same swipe gesture on the editor itself.
I'm looking to understand both why this happens and how to fix it.
I already tried stopPropagation but the odd behavior persists.

Could you share a piece of code or elaborate? Currently you are only saying what your issue is. You need to provide some details.
